# DotNetOpenAuth WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization() always returns null

Tags: c#, .net, dotnetopenauth

I am trying to add implementation of refresh tokens into my API. I'm trying to use `WebServerClient.RefreshAuthorization()`, but that requires the `IAuthorizationState` parameter. The only way I can figure out how to get that is through `WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization()`. The problem is, that method is always returning null, so I can't refresh my token.

```
var state = this.WebServerClient.ProcessUserAuthorization();
this.WebServerClient.RefreshAuthorization(state);
```

Is there a different method I can use on my API that the client can call to refresh their access token? Or is there a different way to get the `IAuthorizationState` of the client? Or anything is sounds like I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

"Facebook has recently shut down API v2.2, and with v2.3 the return format of the access token has changed"

[FacebookApplication.VerifyAuthentication(_httpContext, GenerateLocalCallbackUri()) return null on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094777/facebookapplication-verifyauthentication-httpcontext-generatelocalcallbackuri)

Comment: damn facebook, it breaks my apps every few months and wastes my day each time finding what went wrong.

Comment: I'm glad this helped Adeem, but I'm not verifying against Facebook. We're using our own auth server.