# Did Facebook change their App developers API on March 2017?

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-authentication

Well, I am a new guy who is trying to develop a web application whose user are will be authenticated through Facebook.  I am developing the application in `MVC 4 .Net Framework.` As it's internal programs are already done so I need not to do much coding. I have just put the `API ID` and `Secret Key` in the scope

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterFacebookClient(
                appId: "750397051803327",
                appSecret: "**************************");
```

And here is my Application https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNil8.jpg 
My Application is taking properly the user permission from the user perfectly. https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX9gW.jpg but after taking permission it is not providing the login state of the user by showing such exception https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQgiT.jpg login failed. I debugged form the code end and I observed that it is sending isLoggedin as false https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXp8L.jpg therefore my I am not getting the access.

However 2 days before I am not getting such exception. I was getting data simply fine. Here is a snapshot of my previous data. https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTmgI.jpg

I need that data again, but how? Is there anything need to change in my application dashboard? Possibly I have changed something in application dashboard. if yes then what is particularly that? 
Another things I'm confused that what is the need for PRODUCTS? Do I need anything from the products for this special reason to get the data. If yes then which one shall I need and how to configure it to get back my previous systematic process in which I was getting data smoothly.

If I add `App Center` from the `PRODUCTS` I am obtaining two other secret keys like `Account Kit App Secret` and `Account Kit Client Token` Is that I need to use these keys for my requested case. For such login approval specific which `Products` are need or nothing need at all from `PRODUCTS`. I am so confused about it how to configure an application.

Please suggest me how to solve this problem in addition how to configure my application API. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094777/facebookapplication-verifyauthentication-httpcontext-generatelocalcallbackuri?noredirect=1&lq=1) I got my solution. In `MVC4` everyone write down their `AppID` and `SecurityCode`. Due to change of facebook GRAPH API those previous links are broken. Consequently everyone need to change the `RegisterFacebookClient` calss. But this class is a sealed class in the .Net library, so anyone can't extend or overwrite it. As a result we need to use a `wrapper` class. Let us consider my Wrapper class is `FacebookClientV2Dot3` therefore my class will be

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class FacebookClientV2Dot3 : OAuth2Client
{
    #region Constants and Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// The authorization endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";

    /// <summary>
    /// The token endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";

    /// <summary>
    /// The user info endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";

    /// <summary>
    /// The app id.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string _appId;

    /// <summary>
    /// The app secret.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string _appSecret;

    /// <summary>
    /// The requested scopes.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string[] _requestedScopes;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Facebook OAuth2 client, requesting the default "email" scope.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appId">The Facebook App Id</param>
    /// <param name="appSecret">The Facebook App Secret</param>
    public FacebookClient(string appId, string appSecret)
        : this(appId, appSecret, new[] { "email" }) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Facebook OAuth2 client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appId">The Facebook App Id</param>
    /// <param name="appSecret">The Facebook App Secret</param>
    /// <param name="requestedScopes">One or more requested scopes, passed without the base URI.</param>
    public FacebookClient(string appId, string appSecret, params string[] requestedScopes)
        : base("facebook")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appId))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appId");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appSecret");

        if (requestedScopes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestedScopes");

        if (requestedScopes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("One or more scopes must be requested.", "requestedScopes");

        _appId = appId;
        _appSecret = appSecret;
        _requestedScopes = requestedScopes;
    }

    protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
    {
        var state = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl.Query) ? string.Empty : returnUrl.Query.Substring(1);

        return BuildUri(AuthorizationEndpoint, new NameValueCollection
                {
                    { "client_id", _appId },
                    { "scope", string.Join(" ", _requestedScopes) },
                    { "redirect_uri", returnUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) },
                    { "state", state },
                });
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
    {
        var uri = BuildUri(UserInfoEndpoint, new NameValueCollection { { "access_token", accessToken } });

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (stream == null)
                return null;

            using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var json = textReader.ReadToEnd();
                var extraData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
                var data = extraData.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());

                data.Add("picture", string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", data["id"]));

                return data;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
    {
        var uri = BuildUri(TokenEndpoint, new NameValueCollection
                {
                    { "code", authorizationCode },
                    { "client_id", _appId },
                    { "client_secret", _appSecret },
                    { "redirect_uri", returnUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) },
                });

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        string accessToken = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        // handle response from FB 
        // this will not be a url with params like the first request to get the 'code'
        Encoding rEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), rEncoding))
        {
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
            var jConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject));

            Dictionary<string, object> desirializedJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jConvert.ToString());
            accessToken = desirializedJsonObject["access_token"].ToString();
        }
        return accessToken;
    }

    private static Uri BuildUri(string baseUri, NameValueCollection queryParameters)
    {
        var keyValuePairs = queryParameters.AllKeys.Select(k => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(k) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryParameters[k]));
        var qs = String.Join("&", keyValuePairs);

        var builder = new UriBuilder(baseUri) { Query = qs };
        return builder.Uri;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Facebook works best when return data be packed into a "state" parameter.
    /// This should be called before verifying the request, so that the url is rewritten to support this.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RewriteRequest()
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        var stateString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ctx.Request.QueryString["state"]);
        if (stateString == null || !stateString.Contains("__provider__=facebook"))
            return;

        var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(stateString);
        q.Add(ctx.Request.QueryString);
        q.Remove("state");

        ctx.RewritePath(ctx.Request.Path + "?" + q);
    }
}
```

Look here you I have replaces all the API links by newer version links.

Now you need to modify your

> AuthConfig

Just use a wrapper class

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new FacebookClientV2Dot3("AppID", "HassedPassword"));
```

Then all success. You facebook login will be back in previous state.

However you can face a new issue regarding this new API rather than previous API, the problem is that `IP Whitelisting`. Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOikd.jpg). Hope you will need nothing but this. Happy coding.

Answer (score -1):

Yes!!!! 
I got the solution of my own problem. According to Facebook developers [bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1598154160212440/) report all Facebook log is not working from 28th March 2017. They also let us know through their developers Facebook group. The post [link](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1358398034203707/) is here.

> According to one of the Developer teams had said  we're finding that
>   facebook authentication just stopped working (2pm EST) across multiple
>   apps that we manage. apps haven't changed, apps haven't been
>   suspended..... not sure where to report this since "status" is all
>   good......