# External login is not working for facebook in MVC 4 webapplication

Tags: facebook, asp.net-mvc-4, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I have noticed that after expiration of Facebook GRAPH API  on March 27, 2017 my Facebook application is not providing the access to my web application.
Mainly `OAuthWebSecurity` is failed to fetch the login state from the facebook graph API, I have gone through the [bug](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/permalink/1358398034203707/) report in the developers group. But they didn't provide a solution. I got a solution which is provided for `NopCommerce` in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094777/facebookapplication-verifyauthentication-httpcontext-generatelocalcallbackuri). However I didn't get any perfect solution for `MVC 4`.

I have gone through this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364442/asp-net-mvc5-owin-facebook-authentication-suddenly-not-working) where they system is approached in `MVC 5` however  I need the solution in `MVC4` And mention that `OWIN` is not supported for `MVC4` in `VS 2012`
So how do I solve this problem. I have been undergoing this problem since last 1 week.

Mainly the exception is happening in this piece of code

```
AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
```

It's returning `IsSuccessful` as false and rest of the parameters are null as well.

I have studied that Facebook have changed the the return type of the API `string` to `JSON` So how to develop my code to get those `JSON` exactly. thank you.

**Update:**
This Question is still unanswered. Anyone here to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094777/facebookapplication-verifyauthentication-httpcontext-generatelocalcallbackuri?noredirect=1&lq=1) I got to give you a solution. In `MVC4` everyone write down their `AppID` and `SecurityCode`. Due to change of facebook GRAPH API those previous links are broken. Consequently everyone need to change the `RegisterFacebookClient` calss. But this class is a sealed class in the .Net library, so anyone can't extend or overwrite it. As a result we need to use a `wrapper` class. Let us consider my Wrapper class is `FacebookClientV2Dot3` therefore my class will be

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.Clients;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class FacebookClientV2Dot3 : OAuth2Client
{
    #region Constants and Fields

    /// <summary>
    /// The authorization endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth";

    /// <summary>
    /// The token endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string TokenEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token";

    /// <summary>
    /// The user info endpoint.
    /// </summary>
    private const string UserInfoEndpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com/me";

    /// <summary>
    /// The app id.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string _appId;

    /// <summary>
    /// The app secret.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string _appSecret;

    /// <summary>
    /// The requested scopes.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string[] _requestedScopes;

    #endregion

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Facebook OAuth2 client, requesting the default "email" scope.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appId">The Facebook App Id</param>
    /// <param name="appSecret">The Facebook App Secret</param>
    public FacebookClient(string appId, string appSecret)
        : this(appId, appSecret, new[] { "email" }) { }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new Facebook OAuth2 client.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="appId">The Facebook App Id</param>
    /// <param name="appSecret">The Facebook App Secret</param>
    /// <param name="requestedScopes">One or more requested scopes, passed without the base URI.</param>
    public FacebookClient(string appId, string appSecret, params string[] requestedScopes)
        : base("facebook")
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appId))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appId");

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appSecret))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("appSecret");

        if (requestedScopes == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requestedScopes");

        if (requestedScopes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("One or more scopes must be requested.", "requestedScopes");

        _appId = appId;
        _appSecret = appSecret;
        _requestedScopes = requestedScopes;
    }

    protected override Uri GetServiceLoginUrl(Uri returnUrl)
    {
        var state = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl.Query) ? string.Empty : returnUrl.Query.Substring(1);

        return BuildUri(AuthorizationEndpoint, new NameValueCollection
                {
                    { "client_id", _appId },
                    { "scope", string.Join(" ", _requestedScopes) },
                    { "redirect_uri", returnUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) },
                    { "state", state },
                });
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, string> GetUserData(string accessToken)
    {
        var uri = BuildUri(UserInfoEndpoint, new NameValueCollection { { "access_token", accessToken } });

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        using (var webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
        {
            if (stream == null)
                return null;

            using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var json = textReader.ReadToEnd();
                var extraData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
                var data = extraData.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value.ToString());

                data.Add("picture", string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture", data["id"]));

                return data;
            }
        }
    }

    protected override string QueryAccessToken(Uri returnUrl, string authorizationCode)
    {
        var uri = BuildUri(TokenEndpoint, new NameValueCollection
                {
                    { "code", authorizationCode },
                    { "client_id", _appId },
                    { "client_secret", _appSecret },
                    { "redirect_uri", returnUrl.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path) },
                });

        var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
        string accessToken = null;
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();

        // handle response from FB 
        // this will not be a url with params like the first request to get the 'code'
        Encoding rEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), rEncoding))
        {
            var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
            var jsonObject = serializer.DeserializeObject(sr.ReadToEnd());
            var jConvert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonObject));

            Dictionary<string, object> desirializedJsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(jConvert.ToString());
            accessToken = desirializedJsonObject["access_token"].ToString();
        }
        return accessToken;
    }

    private static Uri BuildUri(string baseUri, NameValueCollection queryParameters)
    {
        var keyValuePairs = queryParameters.AllKeys.Select(k => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(k) + "=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(queryParameters[k]));
        var qs = String.Join("&", keyValuePairs);

        var builder = new UriBuilder(baseUri) { Query = qs };
        return builder.Uri;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Facebook works best when return data be packed into a "state" parameter.
    /// This should be called before verifying the request, so that the url is rewritten to support this.
    /// </summary>
    public static void RewriteRequest()
    {
        var ctx = HttpContext.Current;

        var stateString = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(ctx.Request.QueryString["state"]);
        if (stateString == null || !stateString.Contains("__provider__=facebook"))
            return;

        var q = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(stateString);
        q.Add(ctx.Request.QueryString);
        q.Remove("state");

        ctx.RewritePath(ctx.Request.Path + "?" + q);
    }
}
```

Look here you I have replaces all the API links by newer version links.

Now you need to modify your

> AuthConfig

Just use a wrapper class

```
OAuthWebSecurity.RegisterClient(new FacebookClientV2Dot3("AppID", "HassedPassword"));
```

Then all success. You facebook login will be back in previous state.

However you can face a new issue regarding this new API rather than previous API, the problem is that `IP Whitelisting`. Like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOikd.jpg). Hope you will need nothing but this. Happy coding.

Answer (score 5):

Have you checked this solution?

*"We ran into this same issue on Monday, 3/27/2017, when Facebook discontinued support for their Graph API v2.2.
We are also using DotNetOpenAuth, which was originally installed via Nuget. The source code is available at the link below"*

[FacebookApplication.VerifyAuthentication(_httpContext, GenerateLocalCallbackUri()) return null on Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43094777/facebookapplication-verifyauthentication-httpcontext-generatelocalcallbackuri?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Edit (Apr 18, 2017):
Hello, I've came across the following link this morning and it solved the issue for me. Give it try and let me know :)

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/issues/397

The code is provided by the user 'adoconnection'. it's the 4th post in the link.

I was pulling my hair over this. lol

Best regards!

Comment: Sorry !!! I can't accept your answer. I'm looking for the answer in `MVC 4` not  for `NopCommerce` or `MVC 5`

Comment: Thanks a lot Guilherme! I wish I could give you more votes. Mine is MVC 4 and your link FacebookClient2017 class worked. Thanks again.

Comment: This solution worked, though I was using v2.5 of graph api

Comment: Note: The above link has newer updated code from @Hallmanac for recent facebook api version 3.2.